# How to delete lines from 50000 html files

Tags: algorithm, file

This question was asked in interview, and not sure if stack overflow is right place to ask this.

> Given 50000 html files we need to delete all occurrences of phone number.

I answered, I would read file, parse it and write another file without phone number after filtering.

eg:

```
while ( line = br.readline != null) {
   if line does not have phone number
      write line to another file.
}
```

Also since we had 50000 files, should element of multithreading be involved ?

Any better ideas ? Standard solutions ?

Comment: perl makes this a snap: http://technosophos.com/2009/05/21/perl-pie-if-you-only-learn-how-do-one-thing-perl-it.html

Comment: Is `line` being set to `br.readline` (`string`) or `br.readline != null`  (`boolean`)?

Comment: `sed` would probably be comparable to the perl solution.

Comment: i would use something like sed to remove the phone number, but would probably need more info about how it is used / formatted.  Did they say it was on a line by itself ? If not then you need to careful about omitting the line.  Also i would question how they wound they up with the information duplicated that many times. Lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interview questions come in two major varieties - ones to test your knowledge of a specific technique, and ones to learn about your thinking process. This question sounds like the second variety.

Once you give a solution, the interviewer should probably ask more questions about your code:

- **Is it going to catch all instances of the phone number?** - You would probably think "yes"
- **What about phone numbers split across multiple lines? HTML does not care, right?** - You should explain how to modify your solution to accommodate phone numbers with `'\n'`s in the middle
- **What about mark-up, would you catch phone numbers with HTML tags in the middle?** - You should explain how to change the solution to deal with mark-up. An HTML parser may be useful to do this task right.
- **What if only 20% of the files contain the phone number?** - You should explain that the program is going to be I/O bound, and how you would optimize writing by searching for the first occurrence before starting to write.

The conversation can go on and on. In the end the interviewer should get a pretty good picture of your skills in the areas of HTML, File I/O, and string processing. A good answer would probably include most of the techniques mentioned above.

Comment: This is a great answer. To the point about I/O bound-ness of the problem, you could add that performance is likely to scale with the number of disks (given a core per disk and controllers than can drive each to max rates), and there's an advantage to reading one file at a time per disk and writing to another or else using big buffers or else using solid state disks so that seek time is minimized.

Comment: The part of "What if 20% files contain the phone number" - how can you determine *quickly* if a file contains a substring, if it's already known it can be split with HTML markup? I say I don't care and I'd still do full process on 100% of the files due to inability to quickly determine whether this file actually contains the number. But, if it won't, I'd not write the file with same contents.

Comment: @Vesper You can't determine it quickly, so you need to parse it anyway. The idea was to discuss what's better - 50K reads+50K writes (always write as you read), or 60K reads + 10K writes (read each file with phone number twice, but write only files where the phone has been found).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight 50K reads and 10K writes are better, just use a flag that would indicate if writing was actually required.

Answer (score 1):

Careful now son,

No *cough*, I wouldn't uh use my own algorithm for that, get an app like [fnr.exe](https://findandreplace.codeplex.com/) make sure **it shows what your finding in the html**, preview of replacement/deletion and **how many files** and **occurrences**. Reliable and **faster**.

Doing that operation is **like launching a missile** to be undone, it's better to have a preview of what your going to do and backup, a employer with that kind of question should throw some flags. Or maybe I'm too careful.

Answer (score 1):

I would open the folder in sublime, then run a find and replace all on all files in the folder with some regex. Then save them all.

- Open folder with all the files in  Sublime Text 3
- Find and replace in files using a regex to identify phone numbers
- Save all

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the interviewer might be expecting an out of the box answer, eg not using java at all. If you write a java program, you will have to handle a lot of edge cases, something that is already done in many already available tools. Here is a small shell script to do that

```
for FILE in `ls myDir`
do
   grep -h -v "myPattern" $FILE > $FILE
done
```